# mount an LVM1 raw image

Tags: linux, lvm

I have a raw `dd` image of a LVM1 volume, from an ancient backup, and I cannot mount anymore in recent distros as LVM1 has been removed, and only LVM2 is available.
What should I try to mount it?

I tried to boot an [Ubuntu 12 cloud image](http://cloud-images-archive.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release-20160919/), with QEMU, with no success. Can you point me on working qemu images of old linux distros?

```
# lsblk -f /dev/loop1
NAME  FSTYPE      FSVER LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop1 LVM1_member             qvBl4K-3QK0-wYyg-la09-LGdg-tjCj-Vz5EIu
```

Comment: Debian 9 has the --metadatatype option in its manpage, Debian 10 not anymore. https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/lvm2/lvm.8.en.html versus https://manpages.debian.org/buster/lvm2/lvm.8.en.html